# PHP обрезает принятый массив до 1000 строк

Tags: php, массивы, json, post

Я еще новичек в этом деле. Ситуация такая: отправляю массив строк через JSON, но на сервер приходит только 1000 строк. Как это исправить?

```
var data = DataArr;
alert(data.length);//тут более 1000 строк
if (id == 0) {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'createFile.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {
            '0' : data
        },
        response : 'text',
        success : function(data) {
            alert("Выполнено!");
            DownloadFile(data.path, 0);
        }
    });
    DataArr.length = 0;
}
```

На стороне сервера принимаю:

```
global $file;
if (!empty($_POST['0'])) {
    $rand = uniqid();
    mkdir(dirname(__FILE__) . "/files/" . $rand);
    $dataArr = $_POST['0'];
    echo (count($dataArr));//а тут ровно 1000 строк
    $file = "/files/" . $rand . "/" . $dataArr[0];
    $fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . "/files/" . $rand . "/" . $dataArr[0], "w");

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($dataArr); $i++) {
        fwrite($fp, $dataArr[$i] . "\r\n");
    }
    fclose($fp);
    $json_path = array('path' => $file);
    echo json_encode($json_path);
}
```

Comment: вы присылаете json, а читаете зачем-то чистый $_POST

Comment: со считыванием нет проблем, все адекватно встает на свои места, вот только режет до 1000 строк.

Comment: увеличение `max_input_vars` что-нибудь дает?  и как может резать строки если json - это одна строка?

Comment: ничего не дает, пробовал и php.ini и .htaccess править. Возможно заблокировано значение хостингом?

Comment: Позвонил в техподдержку, сказали, что ограничение в 1000 стоит. Вопрос снят.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увеличь значение max_input_vars в php.ini. По умолчанию PHP оберезает массивы до 1000 строк в POST.